# Dolphin MTP protocol keeps dying when opening Android

Tags: protocol

I tried to open my android phone in Kubuntu and the dolphin file manager keeps saying the mtp protocol died undexpectedly. This has previously worked fine when I used PCMANFM. However, last time I used an OS I loaded PCMAN but then deleted NEMO and the system wouldn't even load so I had to install Kubuntu. I'd rather just get Dolphin working for my Android tablet.

Comment: Solved - I just installed KDE connect and it worked fine. BTW, how do I mark something as solved?

Comment: You can't. The only way is to post an answer and accept when you're allowed to by click on the ✔ near the top left of the answer. BTW, if you're using Kubuntu 18.04, there should be no need to install KDE Connect. It's there by default.